# Apache2, configuration for microsites

Tags: configuration, apache2, subdomain, document-root

Please, I ned help. I'm trying configure microsites with Apache.

I have a main site "mainsite" (www.mainsite.aaa) with document root /a/b/mainsite, in advance ./mainsite for abbreviate.

I want serve some content "minisiteA", "minisiteB" and so on... with they particular domain "www.minisiteA.aaa", "www.minisiteB.aaa"... (there are about 80 minisites) , which principal content but not all, are under ./mainsite/microsite/minisiteA, ./mainsite/microsite/minisiteB. There are a lot references to scrips css, images,etc under ./mainsite/ccs ./mainsite/imgages... It is: "out of the pseudo-documentroot for minisiteX" (That is my main problem at this moment)

I try to resolve this creating a virtualhost to manage all the microsites (ServerAlias) with the same document root as the mainsite (I don´t whant to modify de mainsite vhost). But I don´t locate a soltution for this. I guess that it's a very common configuartion, but I don´t find it (I feel I don't user correct keywords).

I try with some configuration, here two of them, first one the most easiest but it don´t work with files below ./microsite/minisiteX, and the second one has the same problem. It is possible than I am far away of correct solution, so, tips and advisors are welcome.

```
First config.
    RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^www\.minisiteA\.com:8036$
    RewriteRule   ^/(.+)  /microsite/minisiteA/$1    [L]

Second config
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} ="" 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain\.org\.?(:80)?$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdomains/%1 -d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) subdomains/%1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L] 
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 'dynamically configured mass virtual hosting' is what you want here.

Given that the sites follow the same structure you can have Apache map your domain names to your local structure, i.e. by mapping the domain names to folder names using a variable - 'minisiteA' can be mapped to /local/path/minisiteA, 'minisiteB' can be mapped to /local/path/minisiteB ...

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

This has saved me before, having to write 1 config rather than scripting generating hundreds and hundreds of small, almost identical configs...